# How to reference kmm shared library in xcode

Tags: xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

I finished the following tutorial.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-upgrade-app.html

And I had a question below.

### How to build iosApp in Xcode

I was able to run a IOSApp in AndroidStudio. So I tried to run it in Xcode as well.

But I got an error `No such module 'shared'` and could not run it.

Because I want to use `Swift Package Manager`, I selected `Regular framework` when I created the project(not cocoa pod). If I don't select CocoaPods, can I use Xcode to Build? Or am I making some mistakes?

I need to know how to build IOSApp with Xcode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Swift Package Manager you'll need to call the command `./gradlew createXCFramework` to build and create the framework. Then you will need to make a `Package.swift` file to point to the framework file. Something like this:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13),
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["shared"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "shared",
            path: "YOUR_PATH/build/XCFrameworks/debug/shared.xcframework"
        )
    ]
)
```

You can see more details for Package.swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-standalone-swift-package-with-xcode).

You can also try using this gradle plugin to generate it automatically.
https://github.com/ge-org/multiplatform-swiftpackage
I haven't used it personally but it could be a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

according to this [documentation](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/07/multiplatform-gradle-plugin-improved-for-connecting-kmm-modules/)

In the Xcode, Run Script build step, change packForXcode to embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode and remove all the passed flags. The task will use the Xcode environment configuration and build only the needed artifact automatically.

this is mine

```
./gradlew :composeApp:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode
./gradlew :shared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode
```